# Performance issue with timediff()

Tags: mysql

So I'm having a performance problem with a query involving the timediff function.

For each id register in the session table (PK), there are several registers in the study_behaviour table (idsession is a FK from session table in study_behaviour table).

Can you figure out a way to improve the performance in terms of time of this query?

```
create table eficacia_time as
    select s.id,s.iduser,sum(hour(timediff(sb.dateend,sb.dateinit))+minute(timediff(sb.dateend,sb.dateinit))/60) as SesTime
    from study_behaviour sb
    left join session s on s.id=sb.idsession
    where year(sb.dateInit)=2015 and s.iduser in (select userid as iduser from exp)
    group by s.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try 2 things:

1. Add an index to the `sb.dataInit` column if it does not exist, and change the `WHERE` statement to `sb.dateInit BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-12-31 23:59:59'` so that the index can be used.
2. Don't use a subquery, but join the `exp` table with the `study_behaviour` table